# Как получить доступ к методам фрагмента, если есть ссылка на View?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-fragment

Доброго
есть класс к примеру

```
public class ItemConsist extends Fragment {
     public int id = 1; //переменная или метод класса, пофиг
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflat....){}
}
```

создаём экземпляр класса в контейнере, выводя его экземпляр на экран (несколько штук)

```
ItemConsist itemConsist = new ItemConsist();
layoutArrayItemConsist.addView(itemConsist.onCreateView(inflater, layoutArrayItemConsist, new Bundle()));
```

теперь мне нужно получить из этого контейнера значение public int id всех экземпляров ItemConsist. Там несколько экземпляров ItemConsist

```
int index = layoutArrayItemConsist.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; index > 0; ++i) {
            View view = layoutArrayItemConsist.getChildAt(i);
}
```

А как мне из этого View получить значение переменных и методов?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что у вас есть фрагмент? Ваш код эквивалентен `layoutArrayItemConsist.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.someview, layoutArrayItemConsist, false))` Фрагмента тут нет, как и переменных и методов. Работаете с view'шками и не более.

Comment: Пусть эквивалентен, но как получить доступ к методам, которые создал  сам в этом View.

Comment: В каком View вы создали методы? View - это [класс](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) в android SDK.

Comment: В данном случае Вы путаете Fragment и View. Как вариант, наследовать класс ItemConsist от ViewGroup (переопределив необходимые конструкторы и задав разметку через инфлейтор). Или же использователь действительно фрагменты, но не добавлять их через .addView, а соорудить что то похожее на FragmentViewPager, если это подходит под Ваш юзкейс.

Comment: Вот пример кастомной вью, с помощью которой можно обойтись без фрагментов: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/776df81ad9f9ed35f2289d5d5efd4187

Comment: Спасибо, что набросали примерный код, я чёт о таком варианте совсем не думал. Всё получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что бы получить доступ к методам класса наследника надо просто привести объект класса предка к конкретному типу, методы которого Вы хотите использовать. Следует учесть, что downcast (приведение к типу наследника) опасная операция, поэтому, что бы избежать `ClassCastException` желательно провести проверку на соответствие типу:

```
View view = layoutArrayItemConsist.getChildAt(i);
if (view instanceof ItemConsist) {
    ((ItemConsist) view).someMethodOfItemConsist()
}
```

Comment: Прекрасно. Только `ItemConsist extends Fragment` и `View` не является. С таким же успехом можно по view получить и `Activity` и какой-нибудь `ContentResolver` или `Service`. С нулевым успехом.

Comment: @YuraIvanov Это уже совсем другой вопрос. Фрагмент тут вообще костыль, который почему то используется для инфлейта вью. Если сделать ItemConsist extends ViewGroup, например, и заинфлейтить разметку руками, то получиться то, что хотел ТС. Об этом я оставил коммент под его вопросом.

Comment: Вопрос - в заголовке. Если вы отвечаете на другой вопрос, значит 4 человека, поставившие плюс вопросу получат ваш ответ не по теме? С вашим комментарием я не спорю, тут вообще кейс не ясен (мне по крайней мере).

Comment: @YuraIvanov Без проблем, меняем заглавие, показываем автору как надо сделать, даем ответ на вопрос, и все, связь налажена) Мой ответ справедлив для использования хоть фрагментов, хоть вьюх, потому что в общем описывает проблему использования методов наследника, на объекте класса родителя. А вот ТС смешивая фрагменты и вьюхи ставит нас в неловкое положение. Но мы же как прилежные усачники комьюнити можем помочь в выборе правильных решений.